# Weird issue testing a propertysheet

Tags: plone, functional-testing

In `vs.flexigridsearch` I have a test for checking if
the add-on related propertysheet is installed and all its properties.

http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/vs.flexigridsearch/trunk/vs/flexigridsearch/tests/test_flexigrid.py

The first check if `flexigridsearch_properties` is available works:

```
self.assertEqual('flexigridsearch_properties' in pprops.objectIds(), True)
```

All further checks on for properties inside the propertysheet fail
because the propertysheet is empty:

```
self.assertEqual('portalTypesToSearch' in fs_props, True)
```

The propertysheet is defined through GenericSetup:

http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/vs.flexigridsearch/trunk/vs/flexigridsearch/profiles/default/propertiestool.xml

So adding the propertysheet through the fixture seems to work but
the properties are not added. No idea why... However it works
perfectly when I add the add-on through add/remove programs inside Plone
site setup.

Any idea why this is failing in testing environment (Plone 4.0.5)?

Comment: Duplicate to the posting on the product-developer list since posting to the list caused "Message has implicit destination" - feel free to ignore the SO posting.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid me.

One has to use

```
sheet.propertyIds()
```

instead of

```
sheet.objectIds()
```

Comment: Yes, property sheets aren't containers, so they don't support objectIds. Unfortunately they don't support "keys, values, items, __contains__" either so "id in sheet" doesn't work.

Comment: Sure - I know - just of problem of coding-without-enough-tea